# случайное число на fortran

Tags: случайные-числа, fortran

доброго времени суток.
я студент и изучаем мы Фортран.
вот так выглядит задание:
"Write a program for two users, where user 1 provides an integer value. Then user 2 has to guess
the value. Have your program output "higher" or "lower" until the user guessed correctly." - "Написать программу для двух пользователей, к которым пользователь 1 задает целое значение. Затем пользователь 2 должен угадать
это значение."
будет выглядеть нелепо когда заданное первым игроком число будет видно сверху.
поэтому я хотел чтобы программа задала произвольное число.

Comment: в смысле видно сверху ?, это типичная угадайка, случайное число загадывают юзера, просто первый вводит, второй отворачивается, потом программа дает подсказки, больше/меньше. типичная нелепая задача на обучение основам ввода вывода и условием.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы получить случайное число в Фортране, можно вызвать [`random_number()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fNUMBER.html):

```
real :: u
call random_number(u)
```

в этом случае `u` это случайное число в интервале `[0, 1)`. Чтобы получить целое число в диапазоне `[0, n)`, можно вызвать [`floor(u * n)`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/FLOOR.html).

Это в идеальном мире. Но практически `random_number` всё время одну и ту же последовательность возвращает на моей машине, даже если вызывать [`call random_seed`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/RANDOM_005fSEED.html), чтобы инициализировать затравку (seed) для генератора псевдо-случайных чисел (PRNG).

Чтобы это обойти, можно руками взять энтропию из `/dev/urandom` файла или если не доступно, то [использовать текущее время для seed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21257247/4279):

```
subroutine init_random_seed
  implicit none
  integer, allocatable :: seed(:)
  integer :: n, count, i, un, istat

  call random_seed(size=n) ! found out the necessary seed size
  ! use system clock as a fallback for the seed
  call system_clock(count)
  allocate(seed(n), source = count + 37 * [(i, i = 0,n-1)])

  ! use /dev/urandom if available
  open(newunit=un, file='/dev/urandom', access='stream', &
       status='old', action='read', form='unformatted', iostat=istat)
  if (istat == 0) then
     read(un) seed
     close(un)
  end if
  call random_seed(put=seed) ! set seed
  deallocate(seed)
end subroutine init_random_seed
```

Дополнительно, `real` имеет ограниченное количество значащих цифр ([24 для числа одинарной точности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8)), поэтому  чтобы избежать skew, может потребоваться вызывать `random_number()` несколько раз, аналогично тому  как это делает [`_randbelow(n)` в Питоне с `random()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/1dae7450c68bad498e57800387b24cb103c461fa/Lib/random.py#L243-L248).